# Crowdsale Contract, why I can't send ether to contract?

Tags: transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp, payable

Ethereum wallet displays:

```
It seems this transaction will fail.
```

But why? Here is the code:

```
function () payable {
    uint amount = 0;
    amount += msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}
```

This code doesn't throw exception or smth... Please help me. I get Crowdsale contract code from ethereum website

Comment: Could you share the actual code of the contract? You claim to have gotten it from https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale, but the code I see there doesn't match the snippet you've pasted here.

Comment: I think you'll also need to share the address of `tokenReward`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to look for would be whether `tokenReward` is correctly defined , and if it is whether it throws an error or uses too much gas when receiving funds.

To be sure we'd need to see the full contract, and the failing transaction.

Comment: https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale  i got crowdsale contract code from ethereum site

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4fe4eba76cde700f9ad836d9e2e1fda79ddf212ccd40c9b445ba1a8d7f4d50d6

Transaction is here. I passed token address to the constructor of crowdsale contract

Comment: http://ethereum.org/crowdsale  there are few errors in code  where token is defined